# Joomla 301 htaccess redirects not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

i'm adding 301 redirects to a joomla sites htaccess file. but any of these redirects seems not working, i tried a lot by changes urls, etc but no luck, here is my htaccess file.

```
##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
# Redirect addresses which are not www.festsortimentet.dk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.festsortimentet\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.festsortimentet.dk/$1 [R=301,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk/jukeboks http://www.festsortimentet.dk/jukeboks.html
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk/softice http://www.festsortimentet.dk/softice.html
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk/pdf http://www.festsortimentet.dk/slush-ice-popcorn/slush-ice.html
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk/hoppeborg http://www.festsortimentet.dk/hoppeborg.html
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk/telt http://www.festsortimentet.dk/Telt-Borde-Stole.html
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk/mad http://www.festsortimentet.dk/jukeboks.html
redirect 301 /index.php/levering http://www.festsortimentet.dk/levering.html
redirect 301 /index.php/jvthbergskedk http://www.festsortimentet.dk/lejebetingelser.html
redirect 301 /index.php/kontakt http://www.festsortimentet.dk/kontakt/festsortimentet-aalborg.html
redirect 301 /index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=95 http://festsortimentet.dk/jukeboks.html
redirect 301 /index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=104 http://festsortimentet.dk/softice.html
redirect 301 /index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=120 http://festsortimentet.dk/softice/softicemaskiner.html
redirect 301 /index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=121 http://www.festsortimentet.dk/softice/tilbehor.html
redirect 301 /index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=106 http://www.festsortimentet.dk/slush-ice-popcorn/slush-ice.html
redirect 301 /index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=122 http://www.festsortimentet.dk/
```

Ex - i wrote a redirect when user comes with http://www.festsortimentet.dk/index.php/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&category_id=95 url and redirects to http://festsortimentet.dk/jukeboks.html  but not working. can anyone help me please.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `redirect` directive of `mod_alias`. Convert your rule to `mod_rewrite` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop\.browse&category_id=95$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/component/virtuemart/?$ http://festsortimentet.dk/jukeboks.html? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: thank you, working great :) i used
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop\.browse&category_id=95$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/component/virtuemart/?$ http://festsortimentet.dk/jukeboks.html? [R=301,L,NE]

Answer (score 0):

There also is a management for this in joomla 3.x :

- [Joomla Redirect Manager](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/308-redirect-manager)